# When I clone existing android project from github and this error is shown. Could anyone fix it? please help me

Tags: android, kotlin

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.4.0.
> Required by:
> project : > androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.0-alpha05 >
>      androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-generator:2.3.0-alpha05
> > No cached version of com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.4.0 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.4.0 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.4.0 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.4.0 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.4.0 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.4.0 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.4.0 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.4.0 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.4.0 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.squareup:kotlinpoet:1.4.0 available for offline mode.
>
> Possible solution:
> - Disable offline mode and rerun the build

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to gradle on the right hand side
2. Make sure to uncheck this option
3. Rebuild project
   [image]

Comment: Yes sir. I try this way and It's not work

Comment: Could not GET 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/androidx/navigation/navigation-safe-args-generator/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
 "this error is shown" when I try above way

Comment: Can you share screenshot same as i did? Also show your project level build.gradle file

Comment: I cann't post image now sir.